# Python and hobbit monitor

Tags: python, hobbitmon

Here is how I would send data to our hobbit/xymon server in a bash script:

```
$BB $BBDISP "status server.host.com.$TEST $COLOR `date` $LINE"
```

$BB and $BBDISP are environmental variables set by hobbit.
I can't find a python equivalent anywhere here or in the docs. Should be simple but sadly, no.

Answer (score 2):

I assume all variables comes from environment. You could do

```
import os
import subprocess
import datetime

BB = os.environ["BB"]
BBDISP = os.environ["BBDISP"]
TEST = os.environ["TEST"]
COLOR = os.environ["COLOR"]
LINE = os.environ["LINE"]

dat = dat = datetime.datetime.ctime(datetime.datetime.now())

subprocess.call((BB, BBDISP, "server.host.com." + TEST, COLOR, dat, LINE))
```

That's the general idea, that you still have to adapt if :

- you want to process the output of command
- some variable do not come from environment
- ...